# Where did the Drúedain live on Númenor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Drúedain were deformed beings or something of that nature living in Númenor . But I'm interested as to which province they lived in.

Comment: Why do you assume they only lived in one province?

Answer (score 12):

The **only** information about Drúedain in Númenor in all of Tolkien's writings is to be found in a footnote to the Drúedain essay in *Unfinished Tales*, itself extracted from the longer work "Of Dwarves and Men", published in *History of Middle-earth 12*.

> In the annals of Númenor it is said that this remnant was permitted to sail over sea with the Atani, and in the peace of the new land throve and increased again, but took no more part in war, for they dreaded the sea. What happened to them later is only recorded in one of the few legends that survived the Downfall, the story of the first sailings of the Númenóreans back to Middle-earth, known as The Mariner's Wife. In a copy of this written and preserved in Gondor there is a note by the scribe on a passage in which the Drúedain in the household of King Aldarion the Mariner are mentioned: it relates that the Drúedain, who were ever noted for their strange foresight, were disturbed to hear of his voyages, foreboding that evil would come of them, and begged him to go no more. But they did not succeed, since neither his father nor his wife could prevail on him to change his courses, and the Drúedain departed in distress. From that time onward the Drúedain of Númenor became restless, and despite their fear of the sea one by one, or in twos and threes, they would beg for passages in the great ships that sailed to the North-western shores of Middle-earth. If any asked "Why would you go, and whither?" they answered: "The Great Isle no longer feels sure under our feet, and we wish to return to the lands whence we came." Thus their numbers dwindled again slowly through the long years, and none were left when Elendil escaped from the Downfall: the last had fled the land when Sauron was brought to it.

This definitively states that there were Drúedain in the household of Aldarion while he was king of Númenor, so we can say for definite that Drúedain lived in (or near) Armenelos.

There is, unfortunately, no reference to Drúedain to be found in the story of "Aldarion and Erendis", also published in *Unfinished Tales*.

Despite this there's no reason whatsoever to assume that the Drúedain were confined to any one part of the island; although their numbers were presumably fewer than the other Atani, they could have been spread throughout the island.

Answer (score 4):

The Drúedain lived in many domains throughout the ages, including Brethil, Númenor, Drúwaith Iaur and ending up in the Drúadan Forest in the Fourth Age.

As for which specific promontory in Númenor the Drúedain lived on while the island still existed, ***The Silmarillion* never specifies if they were limited to any part of the island.**

More information is located on the [Tolkien Gateway](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dr%C3%BAedain.).